# Return boolean if null

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with patient, agents and messages.

The messages table look like so

| Id | crated_by_patient_id | crated_by_agent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | null | 1 |
| Second | 1 | null |

I'd like for the patient SELECT statement to include a boolean column that checks if the client has already received a message from an agent. This is what my attempt looks like however the null values remain null when they should be true:

```
SELECT 
patient.id AS "id",
first_name AS "firstName", 
(SELECT CASE (SELECT 1 WHERE id IS null) WHEN 1 THEN true ELSE false END FROM message WHERE message.created_by_agent_id != 3 AND message.to_phone_number = patient.phone_number LIMIT 1) AS "requiresReply"
FROM patient 
LEFT JOIN message
ON message.id = patient.last_message_id
```

Comment: Your test expression is `SELECT 1 WHERE id IS null` and from your data `id` is never `null` so the `CASE` won't fire. You need to update the question with the field you actually want to check. At a guess that would be `patient.last_message_id`.  Also check out [Coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL): `select coalesce(null, 1); 1`.

Comment: It sounds like you're rather looking for `SELECT id, first_name, EXISTS(SELECT * FROM message WHERE message.id = patient.last_message_id AND message.created_by_agent_id != 3 AND message.to_phone_number = patient.phone_number) AS "requiresReply" FROM patient`

Comment: The NULL values remain because the subquery doesn't return any rows when no messages are found. The query that @Bergi supplied should give you the desired results. Another issue with your query, although is doesn't of itself cause errors, is not directly using logical evaluations when the desired result is a boolean. Replacing everything from `CASE` through `END` with `id IS NULL` is logically equivalent, is more readable, and reduces the opportunity to introduce defects.